# Downloading large binary files and upload it to SharePoint document library using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am building a SharePoint hosted app that communicates With a REST service, also built by us.

The REST service provides a method to get a file (image or video file, typically 4Mb - 50Mb, but also needs to support larger files, up to hundreds of Mb)

Now I would like the SharePoint app to request a file from the service and store it in a document Library in the hostweb in SharePoint Online.

I have found a few samples on how to do this when uploading a local file, but I am not sure how to handle the binary file in Javascript when it comes from a service.

1.Any Clues on how to do this?

2.How will this perform With large files? Will the file always have to be temporary stored in the browser JavaScript context (as a variable or similar) or is there any way to pipe it directly from the REST service and into the document Library?

Since I am in Control of the REST service, I have the option to set the encoding to what I like, base64 for example.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Research I was able to find an answer.

Most of the examples I found online was regarding file upload from local Client, which implies handling of the local file, e.g. by the File API. Since I am Reading the file from a service, I don't need to consider this, and the result turned out to be simpler than I thought.

The rough process is as follows:

1. Download the data in base64 format
2. Convert the base64 string to an
   Uint8Array
3. From the array, construct a string using the fromCharCode function
4. Use the constructed string as the content in a REST Call to SharePoint

The code below is based on this excellent article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques.aspx

Regarding file sizes, it Works on large files as well (tested on a 100Mb+ file), but of course it takes a bit of time because of the Conversion process as well as the upload. Improvement suggestions are welcome, but for now I am just happy it Works! :)

```
function AlternativeUploadFile() {
    //contains a small image
    var base64String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAA";    
    base64String += "AOCAIAAACgpqunAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6";
    base64String += "QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZ";
    base64String += "cwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACPSURBVDh";
    base64String += "PY/z//z8DuYAJSpMFhrbmidbWE++AWX";
    base64String += "cQTMIAGNogsC2NIW0bEk0UgGn+f3uCl";
    base64String += "dWE29vSgASMDzUeahjQWAiAqUDSDJWF";
    base64String += "qgRqhTkAah7CWARA0ozsZLg1YAARhbo";
    base64String += "FpgQIcIc2kqKZniABlfyjQPZtrRZEgE";
    base64String += "KkwQAlsJDsBrkXEQRIagYqbTMwAACPN";
    base64String += "/ICUra1KwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(base64String).split("").map(function (c) {
        return c.charCodeAt(0);
    }));
    var fileData = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        fileData += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
    }

    var docLibrary = $('#docLibraryNameInput').val();
    PerformUpload(docLibrary, "success.png", '', fileData);

}

function PerformUpload(libraryName, fileName, folderName, fileData) {
    var url;

    // if there is no folder name then just upload to the root folder
    if (folderName == "") {
        url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?" +
            "@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'" +
            "&@TargetLibrary='" + libraryName + "'" +
            "&@TargetFileName='" + fileName + "'";
    }
    else {
    // if there is a folder name then upload into this folder
        url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/folders(@TargetFolderName)/files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?" +
           "@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'" +
           "&@TargetLibrary='" + libraryName + "'" +
           "&@TargetFolderName='" + folderName + "'" +
           "&@TargetFileName='" + fileName + "'";
    }

    // use the request executor (cross domain library) to perform the upload
    var reqExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
    reqExecutor.executeAsync({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": digest
        },
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: fileData,
        success: function (x, y, z) {
            alert("Success! Your file was uploaded to SharePoint.");
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert("Oooooops... it looks like something went wrong uploading your file.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have used your code with accessToken, File is creating but size is showing 0 KB. Thanks
Shrikant
shri.bhongade@gmail.com

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online and a SharePoint hosted app? Does the executeAsync function return success or error?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem below using Flow so that the call can be called from any web page.

[.docx files uploaded to SharePoint through REST API being corrupted. Other file types okay](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256601/docx-files-uploaded-to-sharepoint-through-rest-api-being-corrupted-other-file/256858#256858)