# .docx files uploaded to SharePoint through REST API being corrupted. Other file types okay

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, docx

I have two ajax calls below. First to get the contents of a document on my server into an arraybuffer. Then a second call to a Flow to add the file contents into a new file on SharePoint.

This works fine for other file types, like .txt, but for .docx I get corrupted files. Does anybody know how to do this for .docx files?

javascript.js

```
function uploadfile(){
    var filename = "Doc1.docx"
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'native',
        url: "temp/"+filename,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        },
        ContentType: "application/octet-stream",
        success: function(arraybuffer){
            console.log(arraybuffer);
            arraybuffer = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arraybuffer));
            console.log(arraybuffer);
            var requestdigest = getrequestdigest();
            $.ajax({
                //Flow Http Request to upload file from server
                url: "https://prod-33.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/WORKFLOWID/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SIGNATURE",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                },
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'content': arraybuffer,
                    'name': filename,
                    'requestdigest': requestdigest
                })
            }).done(function(item){
                console.log("SUCCESS "+JSON.stringify(item));
            }).fail(function(error){
                console.log("ERROR "+JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Flow to upload document]

Comment: I've also tried a Flow where I copy an existing .docx file and then update its contents. The result is a corrupted .docx file.

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-docx-file-upon-new-items-in-Sharepoint/td-p/61189   Others with the same exact issue. Unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. The below retrieves the contents of a .docx file. My PHP does a search and replace to modify the .docx file before returning the contents. The PHP converts the contents to Base64. The JavaScript then converts this to a blob. Then the Flow accepts the content and runs the SharePoint "Create file" step, successfully creating an uncorrupted .docx file on the SharePoint.

javascript.js

```
function uploadfile(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'native',
        url: "generatetemplate.php",
        ContentType: "application/octet-stream",
        data: JSON.stringify({
        }),
        success: function(blob){
            console.log(blob);
            var requestdigest = getrequestdigest();
            var filename = "Test.docx";
            blob = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,"+blob;
            $.ajax({
                //Flow Http Request to upload file from local drive
                url: "https://prod-33.westus.logic.azure.com/workflows/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/"+filename+"?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                method: 'POST',
                ContentType: "octet-stream",
                processData: false,
                data: makeblob(blob)
            }).done(function(item){
                console.log("SUCCESS "+JSON.stringify(item));
            }).fail(function(error){
                console.log("ERROR "+JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
    });
}
makeblob = function (dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
        var parts = dataURL.split(',');
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        return new Blob([raw], { type: contentType });
    }
    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
}
```

generatetemplate.php

```
<?php
    function runCurl($url, $post = null, $headers = null, $action = null) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post == null ? 0 : 1);
        if($post != null) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        }
        if($action!=null){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $action);}
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if($headers != null) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Length: 0"
    );
    $data = array("path" => "Test/Test.docx");
    $body = json_encode($data);
    //Flow Http request to get template file .docx file from SharePoint
    $response = runCurl('https://prod-49.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXX', $body, $headers, "POST");
    $pks = explode("\r\n\r\n",$response);
    $pk = $pks[1];
    file_put_contents("temp/test.docx",$pk); //Save it on the server

    $zip_val = new ZipArchive;
    //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
    $pk=file_get_contents("temp/test.docx");
    if($zip_val->open("temp/test.docx") == true){
        $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
        $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);
        $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
        // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
       $message = str_replace("timestamp", $timestamp, $message); //Replace string 'timestamp' with the current timestamp variable
        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip_val->deleteName($key_file_name);
        $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name,$message);
        $zip_val->close();
        $pk=file_get_contents("temp/test.docx");
        $pk = base64_encode($pk);    //Encode the file binary content in base64
        echo $pk; //Echo the base64 content back to the Ajax call in javascript.js
    } else{
        echo("false");
    }
?>
```

Microsoft Flow

The Compose step below is critical. The Input field is filled with "@{triggerBody()['$content']}" minus the quotation marks.

[image: Flow]

Comment: here in javascript.js file in ajax function url means sharepoint url?